# Set notation for 1) x_i and x_j belong to same class. 2) do not belong to the same class?

Tags: notation

Suppose have data X= {x<sub>1</sub>, x<sub>2</sub>,…,x<sub>n</sub> } .
Have a C<sub>I</sub> ={ C<sub>1</sub>,…,C<sub>K</sub>,C<sub>K+1</sub> } , where { C<sub>1</sub>,…,C<sub>K</sub>,C<sub>K+1</sub> }  represent K+1 classes/clusters

How write x<sub>i</sub> and x<sub>j</sub> belong to same class?
Attempt  C<sub>I</sub> (x<sub>i</sub>) =  C<sub>I</sub> (x<sub>j</sub>)

How about x<sub>i</sub> and x<sub>j</sub> do not belong to the same class?
Attempt C<sub>I</sub> (x<sub>i</sub>) ≠  C<sub>I</sub> (x<sub>j</sub>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x_i$ and $x_j$ in the same class you could write $\exists C_l \in C_I$ such that $x_i,x_j \in C_l$ for some $$1\leq l \leq K+1.$$

Similarly, for $x_i$ and $x_j$ in a different class $\nexists C_l \in C_I$ such that $x_i,x_j \in C_l$ for some $$1\leq l \leq K+1.$$

If the classes in $C_I$ are not mutually disjoint, then $C_I(x_i) = C_I(x_j)$ is ambiguous as there may be some classes that contain $x_i$ and $x_j$ and some that contain just one of these elements. It is less ambiguous to say there exists a class where both of elements are contained in it.

Bear in mind notation is not universal and you can even use words instead if you’d like!